# Parallel random distribution

Tags: python, random, iterator, generator

I have two iterators in python and both should follow the same "random" distribution **(both should run in parallel)**. For instance:

```
class Iter1(object):
   def __iter__(self):
       for i in random_generator():
          yield i

class Iter2(object):
   def __iter__(self):
       for i in random_generator():
          yield i

for el1, el2 in zip(Iter1(), Iter2()):
    print '{} {}'.format(el1, el2)
```

output should be somethig like:

```
0.53534 0.53534
0.12312 0.12312
0.19238 0.19238
```

How can I define `random_generator()` in a way that it creates the same random distributions **in parallel** for both iterators.

Note:

- They should run in parallel
- I can't generate the sequence in advance (it is a streaming, so I don't know the size of the sequence)

Thanks.

Comment: Just assign the one yield to a variable and use that variable twice

Comment: If you need two copies of the same iteration, use `itertools.tee`

Comment: Why not generating one and copying it into another?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The memory of `tee` will be linear in the "distance" between the iterators, which can be unbounded. Most RNGs (excluding esoteric ones measuring processor heat and stuff), are determined by a constant state, so there's probably a more memory-efficient way to do this.

Comment: @AmiTavory that's true, but based on the description it sounded to me like the gap would be small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the same seed to each call of `random_generator`:

```
import random

def random_generator(l, seed=None):
    r = random.Random(seed)
    for i in range(l):
        yield r.random()


class Iter1(object):
   def __init__(self, seed):
       self.seed = seed

   def __iter__(self):
       for i in random_generator(10, self.seed):
          yield i


class Iter2(object):
   def __init__(self, seed):
       self.seed = seed
   def __iter__(self):
       for i in random_generator(10, self.seed):
          yield i


# The seed can be any hashable object, but don't use None; that
# tells random.seed() to use the current time. But make sure that
# Python itself isn't using hash randomization.
common_seed = object()
for el1, el2 in zip(Iter1(common_seed), Iter2(common_seed)):
    print '{} {}'.format(el1, el2)
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I'd expect to get different numbers from each because they're taking numbers from the same underlying stream of random numbers.

Comment: When I started, I wasn't going to use the global function `random` and instantiate a new `Random` object, but then got excited when I noticed that `seed` was also a global function. I should re-do this.

Comment: I don't see any reason to declare two `Iter` classes here - why not just create two instances of `Iter1` with the same seed?

Comment: I'm just following the question. I assume in the real situation, the two classes don't necessarily have anything in common,  other than that they both call the same function `random_generator` to get their source of random values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control the random generation number in this way. If you want to do that you should create your own random function. But as another pythonic and simpler way you can just create one object and use `itertools.tee` in order to copy your iterator object to having the same result for your random sequences:

```
In [28]: class Iter1(object):
             def __init__(self, number): 
                 self.number = number
             def __iter__(self):
                 for _ in range(self.number):
                   yield random.random()
   ....:                 

In [29]: 

In [29]: num = Iter1(5)

In [30]: from itertools import tee

In [31]: num, num2 = tee(num)

In [32]: list(zip(num, num2))
Out[32]: 
[(0.485400998727448, 0.485400998727448),
 (0.8801649381536764, 0.8801649381536764),
 (0.9684025615967844, 0.9684025615967844),
 (0.9980073706742334, 0.9980073706742334),
 (0.1963579685642387, 0.1963579685642387)]
```